# elasticsearch match scored keywords

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of keywords with relevancy scores which I want to use to match documents in an elasticsearch index. The goal would be to match documents by input keywords and rank by how a combination of input score and document keyword score.

Example search input:

```
[{
    "name": "golang",
    "score": 0.2
}, {
    "name": "c++",
    "score": 0.13
}, {
    "name": "php",
    "score": 0.07
}]
```

A couple example documents:

```
[{
    "name": "John",
    "location": "USA",
    "scoredKeywords": [
        {
            "name": "php",
            "score": 0.7
        }, {
            "name": "golang",
            "score": 0.3
        }, {
            "name": "java",
            "score": 0.17
        }]
}, {
    "name": "Bob",
    "location": "USA",
    "scoredKeywords": [
        {
            "name": "javascript",
            "score": 0.8
        }, {
            "name": "php",
            "score": 0.01
        }, {
            "name": "golang",
            "score": 0.01
        }]
}, {
    "name": "Dave",
    "location": "USA",
    "scoredKeywords": [
        {
            "name": "golang",
            "score": 0.9
        }, {
            "name": "html",
            "score": 0.4
        }, {
            "name": "css",
            "score": 0.3
        }]
}]
```

I can be as flexible as needed with the mapping.

My idea for ranking would yield something like this:

```
Dave: (overall: 1800)
    golang: 0.9
    rank: (0.9 * 100) * (0.2 * 100) = 1800

    html: 0.4
    rank: n/a

    css: 0.3
    rank: n/a

John: (overall: 490 + 600 = 1090)
    php: 0.7
    rank: (0.7*100) * (0.07*100) = 490

    golang: 0.3
    rank: (0.3*100) * (0.2 * 100) = 600

    java: 0.17
    rank: n/a

Bob: (overall: 7 + 20 = 27)
    javascript: 0.8
    rank: n/a

    php: 0.01
    rank: (0.01 * 100) * (0.07 * 100) = 7

    golang: 0.01
    rank: (0.01 * 100) * (0.2 * 100) = 20
```

Comment: can you show your sample query which you want to make and the expected result, better to share some concrete example which is easy to understand and reproduce

Comment: Updated with an expected result. Unfortunately I'm quite an elasticsearch novice, so the query DSL to accomplish this more or less doesn't exist yet!

Comment: No worries, can you also tell me what will be your search term?

Comment: I would use an optional match on location I think, but it would be weighted quite low in comparison to the keyword ranking.